# First Unity Android game - Weird/unknown In App Purchasing error

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, in-app-purchase

I'm currently building an Android game using Unity 2019.3.0f6.

I'm trying to enable some in-app purchases for some in-game currencty using the Unity Plugin "Easy IAP" and following the video tutorial series on YouTube (https://youtu.be/kMAkYXYL84U). But no matter what I do, I can't get the purchases to go through. I've added them in the Google Play Console and activated them, so I don't understand what is happening.

I've created an entirely empty scene in the project, made a build and uploaded it to the Google Play console (I've tried building driectly to my phone, going through Google's internal app sharing, and even full on releasing it) and using the plugin's debug script, it tells me that the consumables exist and are ready to purchase. Except that when I press the actual button, the Google Pay pop-up comes up and declares that the purchaseable is not available. And even less helpful is the plugin debugger returns that the purchase failed due to an "Unknown" error.

Note, when I do this in the Unity editor, it goes through a fake purchase fine, so I'm inclined to think something is wrong in my Google Play console hence why I'm posting here and not a Unity dedicated forum. I've seen other people ask similar questions and tried following those answers but nothing has worked so far.

Answer (score 0):

Google Play does not allow publishers to buy their own products. So you need to sign up a new Google play account and add it as your test account in Google play developer console.
Try that way

Comment: I don't think this is it since my phone account already isn't the same as the publisher account, but thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I feel really dumb, but it seems to be working now and I haven't touched anything since I posted the question several days ago. I'm guessing that the servers didn't immediately recognize the product activations on the Console so I just had to wait.